# What are the VS 2015 Task Runner keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Without any customizations are there *default* keyboard shortcuts to run grunt or gulp tasks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no default key bindings for TRX.
Note that you can select the TRX window with Ctrl+Alt+Bkspc, tab to the Task pane, and use arrow keys to select a task, but that's accessibility, not binding.

Consider submitting a Send-a-Smile suggestion describing how you'd like key binding to be implemented; it *will* be looked at.